# leetcode #77 combination, why do we need to make a new list?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, combinations

In the leetcode combination problem, I tried to add a list to a list of lists, but the result is a list of empty lists. However, it shows the correct answer when I made a new list identical to the former list and then add the new list into the list of lists.

```
List<Integer> t = new ArrayList<>(list);    //this is making
result.add(t);      //a new list and add it to result
```

Why is it necessary to make a new list?

Here is the sample code given by leetcode:

```
public class Solution {

    List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<List<Integer>> combine(int n, int k) {

        if(k == 0) return res;

        bt(1, n, k, new ArrayList<Integer>());
        return res;

    }

    private void bt(int start, int n, int k, List<Integer> list){

        if(k == 0){

            List<Integer> t = new ArrayList<>(list);
            res.add(t);
            return;
        }

        for(int i= start; i<=n; i++){
            list.add(i);
            bt(i+1, n, k-1, list);
            list.remove(list.size()-1);
        }    
    }


}
```

Comment: please try to proivde more details about your problem and code as well

Comment: You probably are trying to "reuse" `list` and called `list.clear()` after you added it to `result`.